# Can't display SUM of datatable column from linked table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to get the sum of a column in a datatable, where the origin of the data is from a different table than the API used by the datatable.

The datatable is using data from a 'Purchases' table, that is related to the 'Handsets' table, in which the 'SalesPoints' data exists, as you can see from the snippet below. I want to get the sum of the SalesPoints column.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $("#purchases").DataTable({

        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
        },


        ajax: {
            url: "/api/purchases",
            dataSrc: ""
        },

        columns: [
            {
                data: "customer.name"
            },
            {
                data: "handset.name"
            },
            {
                data: "handset.salesPoints"
            },
            {
                data: "datePurchased"
            }
        ],
        responsive: true
    });

});
```

To get this sum, I have included the following code in my Controller:

```
private void ComputeBySalesSalesID(DataSet dataSet)
{
    // Presumes a DataTable named "purchases" that has a column named "handset.salesPoints."
    DataTable table;
    table = dataSet.Tables["purchases"];

    // Declare an object variable.
    object sumObject;
   sumObject = table.Compute("SUM([handset.salesPoints])", "");

      ViewBag.TotalValue = sumObject.ToString();
}
```

To display this sum, I have included '@Html.Label((String)ViewBag.TotalValue)' in my view; when I run the program, this label throws me an exception, saying it cannot be null.

I would seriously appreciate any insight on this as it is preventing me from progressing with a project that is due quite soon. Thanks!

EDIT: View code

```
@model IEnumerable<SmashingTargets.Models.Purchase>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "List";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Sales</h2>



<p>
@Html.ActionLink("My Profile", "Profiles", "Sales", null, new { @class = 
"btn btn-primary" })
</p>

@*Display Sum total*@
<div class="form-group">
@Html.Label((String)ViewBag.TotalValue)
</div>

<table id="purchases" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover     
table-responsive">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Handset</th>           
        <th>Points Earned</th>
        <th>Date Purchased</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>


</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Best practice here is to use with Model. Let the scenario handle through model approach. If you still wanted to go ahead with your approach then First check whether you have any value in sumObject and later try to use <label>Your Lable:</label>@ViewBag.TotalValue

Comment: @Prathyush what would the model approach entail? I don't have any value in sumObject when I run in debug. I've been stuck on this for a while so am open to different approach

Comment: Do you have tables in dataSet.Tables["purchases"]; if yes then can you check whether required data is available or not? Looks like your purchase table is empty

Comment: @Prathyush I have edited the post to show my full view, including "purchases", as I'm not sure what you mean by if I have 'tables' in it